# Accessing URL Parameters with React Router?

Tags: react-router

I read through the documentation and tutorial on URL Parameters in React Router and saw that you *should* be able to [access the parameters in this.props.params](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/06-params#adding-a-route-with-parameters). this.props.params is undefined in my render() function. My URL currently looks like this: `http://localhost:8000/?color=green` and I am trying to access the color value. Is this how you access the parameters or is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a URL parameter using React Router, you would use `this.props.location.query.color` where `color` is the name of the URL parameter you want to get.

Comment: Sadly thats not working for me. I have them in this.props.location.search but not as single values